# Passing user credentials to a Webservice

Tags: web-services, authentication

We have a website that calls a remote web service. This web service is stateless and needs the credentials every time to get the data back.  How do we pass the credentials back and forth? for example a call to

```
string GetAddress( userid,password)
```

Is it ok to store the credentials in a session and pass them across https in post ? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to me it is ok to use session as they will be at server. 
another alternative as per me I dont know it will be useful to you or not but use XML to share credential. I have used such application on my previous project so on that basis I am suggesting you to use xml. OR session over ssl will also be good..

Check it if better way exists.